# Slow requests to Bottle server

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib, wsgi, bottle

Let's run a simple Bottle server:

```
from bottle import route, run
@route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello'
if __name__ == "__main__":
    run(port=80)
```

I wanted to test the speed of the requests with:

```
import requests
for i in range(10):
    requests.get('http://localhost/?param=%i' % i)
```

and then I was about to use multithreading/parallel to also test what happens if 10 requests arrive at the same time, and not one after another... but I was stopped by something strange:

[Animated console of the incoming requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJTFo.jpg)

Each request seems to take precisely 1 second!

**Why such a long time for each request on a Bottle server?** (I know it's a micro-framework, but this is surely not the reason for 1-second to respond!)

PS: it's the same with `urllib.request.urlopen`. This code uses the default `WSGIRefServer`:

> Bottle v0.12.18 server starting up (using WSGIRefServer())...

and was tested on Windows 7 + Python 3.7 64 bit.

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you use a `requests.Session` (keepalive)?